# Hosting a wordpress blog on a server with other web sites

Tags: wordpress, installation, hosting

I have a wordpress installation on its own folder, on my server that hosts another site (non-wp) to. I want to keep the wp installation to its own sudirectory, but change the url to point directly to the blog (to get rid of /wp in the url).
Is it possible?
How does the index.php have to be configured to correctly point to both sites hosted?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the subdomain in something like your cPanel with the web hosting.

Example:
I want to have: `blog.domain.com` and `www.domain.com`

`www.domain.com` is set by default.

In your hosting settings, you will need to create the `blog` sub-domain and have it point directly to another directory.